# Как изменить стандартный журнал вызовов?

Tags: android, java

Всем добрый вечер.

Возник следующий вопрос.

Я хочу добавить дополнительную кнопку в элемент списка в журнале звонков на андроид. Уверен, что это можно сделать, но вот где нарыть об этом инфы, не знаю и не понимаю, как гуглу правильно сформировать запрос.

Может, кто сталкивался с кастомизацией стандартных окон андроид, и что есть посоветовать?

Буду рад любой помощи!

С уважением, Меликов Иван.

Всем большое спасибо.

Comment: Просто напишите свою звонилку. И не нужно "кастомизировать" отдельные окна.

Comment: А как ею заменить стандартную? Чтобы при нажатии на журнал попадать в мое ПО? Вообще, есть что-нибудь подобное где-нибудь посмотреть, понять, что к чему?

Comment: @vanyamelikov, да, это описано в многочисленных книгах( в базовой части ) по программированию в среде Android. Т.е, опять же, стоит сперва прочитать хотя бы 1 книгу, чтобы отсеять 95% вопросов.

---

Проблема Android в том, что порог вхождения в SDK слишком низок, поэтому слишком много "программёров" развелось, желающих получить максимум за минимум времени..